# Making main section of a page fill the remaining height with CSS only

Tags: css, layout

I have two divs as shown below:

```
<div class="header">
    <h1>My Cool Site</h1>
</div>

<div class="main">
    Hello world
</div>
```

The header div should take up as much space it needs. The main div should fill the remaining page height exactly - a scroll bar should not appear. Is this possible to do with CSS only? No JavaScript. Here's my unsuccessful attempt at doing this: http://jsfiddle.net/nareshbhatia/HrsHR/

**Edit:**
I changed the jsFiddle a little to clarify the intent that the content area must expand to the full height. The content of "main" has now been replaced by an SVG element which stretches to the full area of the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/HrsHR/3/)**

```
.main {
    background-color: #BAA378;
    border: 10px solid #453823;
    padding: 10px;
    height: calc(100% - 60px); /* 100% - height of header */
}
```

Or you could drop that and use jQuery:

**[Working Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/HrsHR/4/)**

```
 layout = (function () {
     var w = $(window).height();
     var h = $('.header').outerHeight();
     var x = w - h;
     $('.main').outerHeight(x);
 });

 $(document).ready(layout);
 $(window).resize(layout);
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to calc(). It works! Since this is marked as an experimental feature I would not use it in production code, but nevertheless interesting! It appears that there may not be a bullet-proof CSS solution for this, so I am leaning towards using JS.

Comment: Yes, your second example is what I implemented as it will work in more browsers. Although the first example will not work in all browsers, I am marking your answer as correct since it is "technically" a CSS only solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. This positions your div at the bottom.

```
.main {
   background-color: #BAA378;
   border: 10px solid #453823;
   padding: 10px;
   height: 86%;
   position:fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DCM8E/

Comment: overflow: hidden on the body cuts off the main section abruptly (you cannot see the bottom border). So this solution does not work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work either. There is a gap between header and main which changes as the window is resized.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the appearance you want by having a wrapper to create the border instead of your content. Then your content div doesn't occupy the full height, but appears in normal place below the header, and is trimmed to height by `overflow: hidden;`. A little cheating to put the header over the wrapper border, and you have what you need appearance-wise at least.

http://jsfiddle.net/AjtFc/3/

Comment: Very creative! Definitely learned a new technique. However, as you said, this is a little cheating since the content does not occupy the full height. I have changed my jsFiddle a little to leverage the full height of the content area, just so that the intent is clear. Thanks again, for such a creative answer.